# Is there a way to self-reference an entity using Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring JPA and MySQL as the database. I have trouble with self-referencing its own entity.

I know the code below would do self-referencing, but it actually creates a new table to do so.

```
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Member extends BaseTimeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "member_id")
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "followings_id")
    private List<Member> followings = new ArrayList<Member>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "followers_id")
    private List<Member> followers = new ArrayList<Member>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "blocked_id")
    private List<Member> blocked = new ArrayList<Member>();
    
    ...
}
```

[image]

**Question: I'm wondering if I can do this in a single table(which would be the `member` table) without creating a new table to do many-to-many self-referencing.**

Comment: Could you describe what database structure you *want* (or expect) to see? If your relationships are truly many-to-many, then you will probably be forced to use at least one join table.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I am forced to use at least one join table. This was the question that I was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible,

Instead of using the **@ManyToMany** annotation, you can use the **@OneToMany** and **@ManyToOne** annotations to create the self-referencing relationship

```
@Getter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Member extends BaseTimeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "member_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "follower")
    private List<Follow> followings = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "following")
    private List<Follow> followers = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "blocker")
    private List<Block> blocked = new ArrayList<>();
    
}

@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Follow {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "follower_id")
    private Member follower;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "following_id")
    private Member following;
   
}

@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Block {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "blocker_id")
    private Member blocker;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "blocked_id")
    private Member blocked;
   
}
```

Now **Follow** and **Block** entities represent the **many-to-many** relationships between **Member** entities and **follower** and **following** properties in the **Follow** entity represent the two sides of the many-to-many relationship, and the same is for blocked and blocker.

Comment: Would it be possible to do it as List<Member> instead of List<Follow> without creating the `follow` table?

Comment: Becaue by implementing the answer that you have it actualy creates 2 more tables